# `df.loc` return series instead dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y"], ["XX", "YY"]])

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],
                   [5,6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16]], index = index, columns = columns)
```

and a slice `slice_ = ((slice(None), slice(None)), ("X", "XX"))`. Unfortunately `df.loc[slice_]` returns  `Series` instead `DataFrame`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

Either wrap the columns' slice in `[]`:

```
slice_ = ((slice(None), slice(None)), [("X", "XX")])
df.loc[slice_]
```

or, if you don't want to alter the slice, convert back [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

```
slice_ = ((slice(None), slice(None)), ("X", "XX"))
df.loc[slice_].to_frame()
```

output:

```
       X
      XX
A AA   1
  BB   5
B AA   9
  BB  13
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
df.loc[((slice(None), slice(None)), [("X", "XX")])]
```